# Test only one job out of many spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have two jobs. I am trying to test 1 single job.

this is what I am trying:

```
@Autowired
private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("jobNumber1")
private Job job;

@Test
public void test() {
    try {
        jobLauncherTestUtils
                .getJobLauncher()
                .run(job, new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString("--spring.batch.job.names", "jobNumber1")
                .toJobParameters());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But when I see logs, it is running both jobs. How do I make it test only 1 test? Thanks

I have also tried to add a Job in in JobLauncherTestUtils

```
@Bean
public JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils() throws Exception {
    return new JobLauncherTestUtils() {
        @Override
        @Autowired
        public void setJob(@Qualifier("jobNumber1") Job job) {
            super.setJob(job);
        }
    };
}
```

and do `jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob()`. Still both jobs are running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a Spring Boot parameter (`--spring.batch.job.names`) as a Spring Batch parameter. So Spring Boot is not aware of it and will still run both jobs. You need to either:

- pass the `--spring.batch.job.names=jobNumber1` to the command line you are using to test your job
- or add the `spring.batch.job.names=jobNumber1` in the `application.properties` file of your test resources

Hope this helps.

Comment: meanwhile, I am testing this appliction-test.properties approach

Comment: I love you brother. adding `spring.batch.job.names=jobNumber1` to application-test.yml resolved the issue. Also, as stated in the question, Autowiring jobNumber1 in `JobLauncherTestUtils` bean is also important. Thanks

Comment: Also had to load that application-test.yml file on the test class also worked: `@TestPropertySource("classpath:/aplication-test.yml")` . Even this works without application-test.yml: `@TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.batch.job.names=jobNumber1"})`

Comment: Great! Glad to help!